# Get the entire row's data inside a cell in AgGrid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using `AgGridReact`, but this is a general question about how to get the entire row's data inside a cell in that row using AgGrid.

I'm using a custom cell renderer for a certain cell (whose field is `id`) in which I need to get the entire row's data and not just the `id` field's data.

This is how the grid is defined:

```js
<AgGridReact
    rowData={users}
    frameworkComponents={{
        idRenderer: IdRenderer,
    }}
>
    <AgGridColumn field="id" cellRenderer="idRenderer"></AgGridColumn>
    <AgGridColumn field="name"></AgGridColumn>
    <AgGridColumn field="phone"></AgGridColumn>
    <AgGridColumn field="email"></AgGridColumn>
</AgGridReact>
```

Here's the `IdRender` component (used to customize the look of the `id` field's cell) where I need to get the row's data:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function IdRenderer(props) {
    // the following currently stores the cell's value in `rowData`
    const rowData = props.valueFormatted ? props.valueFormatted : props.value;

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(rowData);  // get the entire row's data here instead of just this cell's value
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            {/* some components */}
        </>
    );
}

export default IdRenderer;
```

I'm not able to figure out from the docs what should I add to the grid or the cell renderer to be able to get the entire row's data inside the `id` field's cell (where I'll be posting the data to an API on a button click).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging through the docs for a long time I finally found the way to achieve this: **using a [valueGetter](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/value-getters/)**. I decided to post this Q&A to help others in figuring out how to achieve the same.

Just define the following value getter for the row's data:

```js
const rowDataGetter = function (params) {
    return params.data;
};
```

and use it on the `AgGridColumn` by setting the `valueGetter` prop:

```js
<AgGridColumn field="id" cellRenderer="idRenderer" valueGetter={rowDataGetter}></AgGridColumn>
```

Now `rowData` in `IdRenderer` will contain the entire row's data instead of the cell value.

Comment: what if data is undefined ? in an otherwise working grid